# Sign in user on server for testing purposes

Tags: testing, meteor

I do some integration tests using velocity + mocha. For some server tests a user must be logged in (Meteor.userId and so on must have a valid id). How do I sign in a user on the server (loginWithPassword is not available there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.setUserId` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_setUserId)) in a Meteor method and call it before you do any tests.

E.g

//in your tests code on the server side

```
Meteor.methods({
    signMeIn:function() {
        this.setUserId("<_id of a user>");
    }
});
```

Then run this on the server or client before you want the user to be logged in.

```
Meteor.call("signMeIn");
```

You haven't specified any information about where you're using the userId, but since you said Meteor.userId() I'm assuming its a method. You can also run this piece of code (`this.setUserId`) earlier in your existing testing method too.

Comment: I get `Error: Can't call setUserId on a server initiated method call`